# Draw intersecting 2d plane on 3d surface using matplotlib

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a dataframe with number of features (say `F1`, `F2`, ...) and predicted values (say `P1`). For the ease of use I have created a 3d visualization of my ML model's results using matplotlib 3d surface where end-user can see how the target (`P1`) changes as a function of (`F1` and `F2`).

Now I want to add another 2d surface and find out intersects of these two surfaces graphically. This can enable user to set the target value (`P1`) and see all possible values of `F1` and `F2` (producing equal or below the target value).

In short, I am trying to draw a 2d Plane in 3d space when `z==0.5` (say) and find the line of intersection with my 3d surface (possible x and y values for given z).

Code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
```

1. I created a Tri-surface like below:

```py
 ax.plot_trisurf(df[F1], df[F2], df[P1], cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, 
 antialiased=False)
```

I got some plot like below:
[Trisurf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikTyk.png)

2. Then I tried ax.plot_surface in order to add another 2d plot. It was not possible with ax.plot_trisurf. And added another 2d plane there.

   ''Create the 2D-arrays from 1d df column''

```py
 x1 = np.linspace(df[F1].min(), df[F1].max(), len(df[F1].unique()))
 y1 = np.linspace(df[F2].min(), df[F2].max(), len(df[F2].unique()))
 x2, y2 = np.meshgrid(x1, y1)
 z2 = griddata((df[F1], df[F2]), df[P1], (x2, y2), method='cubic')

 surf = ax.plot_surface(x2, y2, z2, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.1)
 cset = ax.contourf(x2, y2, z2, zdir='z', offset=48, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
```

Then I get a plot like below:
[plot_surface + contourf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DboIH.png)

I want to know the intersect of these two plots.

One way is using grids of 10k by 10k points and identifying the closest ones for each point and connect them to draw an intersecting line, but I was wondering if there is any graphical way to find out.

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you post some code you have written to solve your problem?

Comment: Can you please post some code? It's much easier to follow your question if there is some code. You can post a minimal working example and then point out where you got stuck.

Comment: Hi @Samuel, I have added the code and figures in the question itself.

Comment: Please format your code blocks. See here for reference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @Samuel, I am learning the formatting. Thanx